# limit column count for access crosstab

Tags: ms-access, multiple-columns, crosstab

I have an Access Crosstab query that aggregates data from two tables; 
I want to limit the number of columns it returns.
The columns are date fields and I'd like to limit the return to a maximum of 16 weeks out (each column is a week.)

Is there an easy way to do this in SQL without actually running a report and setting a specific limit therein?

I'd like to query further upon these results so it would be ideal to only generate 16 weeks worth of data for the crosstab.

Answer (score 1):

In your query you need a WHERE clause to restrict the rows that are returned. For example,

```
WHERE [DateField] > Date() - 16*7
```

that is, from 16 weeks ago to today (and beyond) or

```
WHERE [DateField] Between Date()-16*7 and Date()
```

or a variation of these.